# How to query mongodb for existing data on click from client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I am creating a express app where a user can search movies and add them to lists. If it's already added to list, I want to display 'Already added' instead of 'Added to list'. How can I query this from client side when the button is clicked.

**server.js** /search route

```
app.post('/search', (req, res) => {

    const id = req.body.id;
    const title = req.body.title;
    const rating = req.body.rating;
    const description = req.body.description;

    async function getMovie() {
            await AddedMovie.findOne({id: id}, (err1, succes) => {
            
            if (!succes) {
            
            const movie = AddedMovie({
                id: id,
                title: title,
                rating: rating,
                description: description
            })
    
            movie.save();
        }
        })
    }

    getMovie()
    .then(() => res.redirect('/search'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
})
```

Here I managed to save the movie to the list when the button is clicked, and it doesn't save when its already present in the db.

**serach.ejs**

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.addbtn');
    const ids = document.querySelectorAll('#hidden');
    const titles = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
    const ratings = document.querySelectorAll('.rating');
    const descriptions = document.querySelectorAll('.description')
    const success = document.querySelectorAll('.added');

    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i ++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            
            success[i].innerHTML = 'Successfully added to your list.';
            success[i].style.display = 'inline';
            setTimeout(() => {
                success[i].style.display = 'none';
                success[i].innerHTML = '';
            }, 4000);

            $.post('/search', {id: parseInt(ids[i].textContent), title: titles[i].textContent, rating: parseInt(ratings[i].textContent), description: descriptions[i].textContent })
        })
    }
```

The div displays *'added'* when clicked, How can I display *'Already present'* when its saved in database previously.

Answer (score 0):

Update server.js to return the result of the find/add. In your case, if your `findOne` returns a successful result, return "Already Added" in your response. If `findOne` fails, add the movie and return "Successfully added to your list."

Update your client code to say "Adding to your list..." or something similar when the button is pressed and add a [success handler](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to your `post`.

In your handler, you can grab the message that was sent from the server and display it.

Comment: I cant do res.send because I am redirecting in the promise return. How do I return a string in the response along with res.redirect('/search')?

Comment: What is the purpose of the redirect? If you are hitting the server with AJAX requests, you don't need a redirect. If it's to keep the client on the same page, you can prevent the browser refresh on the client-side.

Comment: I removed the redirect, now if you could just tell me how to send the messages ('Added' and 'Already present') and access the response object in the client side either using ajax or fetch, i would appreciate it alot. Thank you for your time.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.json something along the lines of `res.json({status: "success", "statusText": "Successfully added to your list."})` and `res.json({status: "duplicate", "statusText": "Already added to your list."})`. Maybe `status` is unnecessary or maybe it should be `res.status(409).json({ message: 'Duplicate entry received"' })`.

Comment: I have searched a lot, How do I access that res.json() in the javascript in ejs views? Like I get it does send a json object but how do I get that data ? Please help.

Comment: See [this link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) in my answer above. You add a callback to your `$post(url, data, CALLBACK)` and you handle the response JSON in the callback.